# Lookup same keys in multiple hiera files in puppet using lookup command

Tags: puppet

I am trying to read a key present in multiple hiera files and merge the values. 
My hiera file contains:

```
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-env secrets"
    paths:
      - "puppet/hiera/dict-1.yaml"
      - "puppet/hiera/dict-2.yaml"
```

and My puppet script contains:

```
lookup(dictionaries,Hash).each |String $keyDico, Hash $valueDico| {
  notify{"The value of dictionary is: ${keyDico}": }
```

The key 'dictionaries' is present in both dict-1.yaml and dict-2.yaml. However, It always reads and prints the Key from the first matched hiera file. 

I tried changing 'Hash' in lookup function's argument to 'Unique' or 'Deep'. But it didn't work. 

Getting error:
`Error: Evaluation Error: Resource type not found: Deep` and `Error: Evaluation Error: Resource type not found: Unique`


Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the docs for specifying merge behaviours ([ref](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.2/hiera_use_function.html#merge-behaviors)), you can see that you need to specify the optional third argument to `lookup`, and you are getting that error because "unique" is being interpreted as the data type.

Try either:

```
lookup(dictionaries, Hash, 'unique')
```

or

```
lookup(dictionaries, Hash, {'strategy' => 'unique'})
```

according to whichever you find more readable.